# Client doesn't return when you create a client class ROS2

Tags: c++

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi community,
I would like to write a client and server node using classes. I started writing the client in a class "form" using the tutorial in the documentation and I used the same messages and the same identical code for the server node.
I wanted to create a client class which is querying each 500ms the same msg to the server. Searching on the ROS Answer I found a similar [question](https://answers.ros.org/question/340389/client-doesnt-return-when-declared-inside-c-class-in-ros-2/). And using a solution like that I got that the client now is stuck in a deadlock or similar because send the first request but later no and the code continue to run.

The client that I had written is this:

```
#include "rclcpp/rclcpp.hpp"
#include "example_interfaces/srv/add_two_ints.hpp"

#include <chrono>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <memory>
#include <functional>

using namespace std::chrono_literals;


class client_foo : public rclcpp::Node
{
    public:
    client_foo(const std::string &node_name) : rclcpp::Node(node_name)
    {
        client_ = this->create_client<example_interfaces::srv::AddTwoInts>("servizio", rmw_qos_profile_services_default);
        cb_grp_client_ = this->create_callback_group(rclcpp::callback_group::CallbackGroupType::MutuallyExclusive);
        
        while (!client_->wait_for_service(1s))
        {
            if (!rclcpp::ok())
            {
                RCLCPP_ERROR(get_logger(), "Errore mentre aspetto");
                exit(1);
            }
            RCLCPP_INFO(get_logger(), "Servizio non disponibile aspetta...");
        }
        
        timer_cb_ = create_wall_timer(500ms, std::bind(&client_foo::start, this));
    }

    private:
        rclcpp::Client<example_interfaces::srv::AddTwoInts>::SharedPtr client_;
        rclcpp::callback_group::CallbackGroup::SharedPtr cb_grp_client_;
        // Timer per il callback
        rclcpp::TimerBase::SharedPtr timer_cb_;

        example_interfaces::srv::AddTwoInts::Response::SharedPtr start()
        {
            auto request = std::make_shared<example_interfaces::srv::AddTwoInts::Request>();
            request->a = 1;
            request->b = 2;

            auto result = client_->async_send_request(request);
            result.wait();

            RCLCPP_INFO(get_logger(), "Results!");
            return result.get();
        }
};


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    rclcpp::init(argc, argv);
    rclcpp::executors::MultiThreadedExecutor exe;

    std::shared_ptr<client_foo> client_node =
        std::make_shared<client_foo>("client_foo");

    exe.add_node(client_node);
    exe.spin();
    return 0;
}
```

Probably the question is very silly but I don't get the point where the code fails.
Someone can help me?

Thank you so much.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/376473/client-doesn%27t-return-when-you-create-a-client-class-ros2/) by [Kappa95](https://answers.ros.org/users/61250/kappa95/) on ROS Answers with karma: 91 on 2021-04-19

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I think you're on the right path, but two points:

1. The callback group that you created
   is `MutuallyExclusive`, which means
   that callbacks from the same node
   cannot be run in parallel. This
   means that while your `start` callback
   from the timer is still running, no
   other callback on the same node can
   be started, like the service
   callback--you don't specify a
   callback but under the hood there is
   still a callback that is queued for
   when the result arrives. Because you
   `.wait()` on the result in the timer
   callback, the service is blocked,
   the result doesn't actually arrive,
   and `.wait()` never returns, i.e.
   you've got a deadlock. Instead, you
   need to create a `Reentrant`
   callback group, which does allow
   callbacks on the the same node to
   run in parallel:

   ```
   cb_grp_client_ = this->create_callback_group(rclcpp::callback_group::CallbackGroupType::Reentrant);
   ```

That, or you create
two separate groups.

2. You aren't actually using the
   callback group. You have to pass it
   when you create the client:

   this->create_client<example_interfaces::srv::AddTwoInts>("servizio", rmw_qos_profile_services_default, cb_grp_client_)

and when you
create the timer:

```
    create_wall_timer(500ms, std::bind(&client_foo::start, this), cb_grp_client_);
```

Otherwise both use the
default group which is again
`MutuallyExclusive`.

---

Originally posted by [sgvandijk](https://answers.ros.org/users/72841/sgvandijk/) with karma: 649 on 2021-04-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Kappa95](https://answers.ros.org/users/61250/kappa95/) on 2021-04-19**:
Thank you so much! The answer is very clear! So it means that each time I'm creating a service or a client I am using a thread; and in this case I was using 2 threads: one for the client and one for the start callback. In this case having the group with the mutual exclusion, one thread was waiting the end of the other, but they were stuck. Do I understand right?

**Comment by [sgvandijk](https://answers.ros.org/users/72841/sgvandijk/) on 2021-04-20**:
Well, actually by default as many threads as you have cores are created, and they just pick up work to do whenever they are ready, where work can be running a callback function or sending a service request etc. You can't predict which thread handles which bit of work. Because normally you probably don't want multiple bits of code in the same node to run at the same time, to prevent race conditions and such, the default callback group ensures that that doesn't happen and that the callbacks are 'mutually exclusive', even if they happen to be picked up by different threads.

So on the flipside, by using a reentrant group (or multiple mutual exclusive ones in the same node) you possibly open yourself up to this kind of dangers. That is why it is good practice to use proper async calls where possible and then be able to use the standard group, i.e. don't `.wait()` on futures, but handle their result just in callbacks.